# Are book and movie titles italicized when mentioned in dialogue?

Tags: formatting, titles

Just to be clear: I understand the rules on punctuating all manner of titles in writing. I want to know do these rules apply when used in dialogue.

Comment: Why would they not? It's still necessary to distinguish titles from ordinary words. As I was told at school; Hamlet is a man, _Hamlet_ is a play.

Comment: @KateBunting That may be true, but "Hamlet" is a play.  OP wants to know if he quotes his teacher saying "Hamlet is a man, "Hamlet" is a play." Is that grammatically correct.

Comment: @hszmv - Of course it is. As I said, why should the rules be different just because the play is mentioned in a line of dialogue?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, titles of books, films, TV shows, and plays should either be itallicized or put in quotes (In the case of TV shows, if the show is written in one way, an episode title will be written in the other.).

In quotes, it's generally best to use italicization for the title.  That said, any quote within a quote should be denoted by the use of single quotation marks (''), so a character could say "I once read 'A Christmas Carol'."  Do note, that this is in American English (U.S., Canada) while British English (U.K. Australia, NZ) quotes normally use the single quotation mark while quotes within quotes use the double quotation mark ("").  As for anything to the level of a quote within a quote within a quote and beyond, it's generally accepted that you're just trying to be difficult (Best I've seen is to alternate between double and single for each level from the third and beyond.).

Comment: I was once told that if you're going to triple-nest quotes, "You should write it something like this: 'I was once told that if you're going to triple-nest quotes, "You should write it something like this: 'I was once told that if you're going to triple-nest quotes, "You should write it something like this: 'I was once told that if you're going to triple-nest quotes, "You should write it something like this: 'I was once told that if you're going to triple-nest quotes, "You should write it something like this...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman:  I've never seen it one way or another, but I did Mock Trial in High School and that may bleed into my for fun writing... A quote in a quote is in effect a hearsay and should be avoided.   A quote within a quote within a quote is double hearsay.  But that's more personal style.  Because so much of my for funsies writing is aimed at a teen audience, I'm sure I've done a gossip character (with a valley girl accent to boot) who does the typical "Alice told me that Bob said that Charlie told him and Dave that Emily heard... ....that Zack said "She was into it when we dated." +

Comment: @DarrelHoffman +Other than the "get to the point" nature of the gag, I just want to point out that the progression of names and the ellipses implying more sources were quoted between Emily and Zach, I don't think I ever had a "Teen Sourcing Gag" that actually went 26 people deep, but the point is the gossip is citing every grape on the vine that s/he heard the gossip through (usually my High School gossip is sourced from a group of 5-6 kids who's names are loosely inspired by the protagonists from the Animorphs series and never get an "on screen" appearance.